# Problem setting text property of a combobox on application start in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I am using the combocheck example from the following site:
http://www.carballares.es/en/arcadio/?p=220

It's a very useful component and works very well.

Now, I need to set the text property of this combo box upon application startup with certain values (which are defined dynamically according to some criteria).  The problem is that although I have no problem setting the text property of the combo box at other times of the application run, setting the property at startup seems to have no effect unfortunately.

For example, I want to set the text property of the combobox to "Bob" (which is one of the items in the dataprovider for the combobox) and the "set text" method is called on the combo box.  Performing a step-through shows that the "set text" method is receiving the correct value item but not setting the _text property.

I have tried not doing anything until "ApplicationComplete" but no joy there either.

Thanks in advance for any help or clues you can offer up.

//Edit
Here is the code (a combination of the code from the URL above and some other changes to it).  However, as I've stated above, the codes *does* work.  The problem is that it doesn't work at the application startup.  Whenever an event is fired and setComboText is called as a result, the text of the combo box is set correctly.

```
    private function onComboChecked(event:ComboCheckEvent):void {
        var obj:Object=event.obj;
        var index:int=selectedItems.getItemIndex(obj);
        if (index==-1) {
            selectedItems.addItem(obj);
        } else {
            selectedItems.removeItemAt(index);
        }

        setComboText();

        dispatchEvent(new Event("valueCommit"));
        dispatchEvent(new Event("addItem"));
    }

    public function setComboText():void {

        if (selectedItems.length>1) {
            // text='multiple'
            //modified by samuel

           var items:ArrayCollection = selectedItems;
           var selItems:String = "";

           for (var item:String in items) 
           {  
                if (items[item].label != "ALL" ) {
                 selItems = selItems + items[item].label + ",";
                }
           } 

           if (selItems.length > 0){
                selItems = selItems.substr(0,selItems.length - 1);
           }


           text = selItems;
        }
        if (selectedItems.length==1) {
            text=selectedItems.getItemAt(0)[labelField];
        }
        if (selectedItems.length<1) {
            //modified by samuel
            text="ALL";
            //Alert.show("text is "+text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this method into the main ComboBox component you're extending :

```
        public function set selectedValueList( val : String ) : void {
            var selectedValueArray :Array = val.toLowerCase().split(',');
            var dp :ArrayCollection = this.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
            var newSelectedItems:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
            for each ( var selectedVal :String in selectedValueArray ){
                for( var i :uint=0;i<dp.length;i++){
                    if( String(dp.getItemAt(i)[this.labelField]).toLowerCase() == selectedVal ){
                        newSelectedItems.addItem( dp.getItemAt(i) );
                    }
                }
            }
            selectedItems = newSelectedItems;
            if (selectedItems.length>1) { text='multiple'; }
            if (selectedItems.length==1) { text=selectedItems.getItemAt(0)[labelField]; }
            if (selectedItems.length<1) { text=''; }            
            dispatchEvent(new Event("valueCommit"));
            dispatchEvent(new Event("addItem"));
        }
```

Then you'll call it like this when you want to set the selected items :

```
myComboId.selectedValueList = 'Selected Label 1,Selected Label 2';
```

Or set it in the component mxml def:

```
<local:ComboBox selectedValueList="Selected Label 1,Selected Label 2" ...rest of properties.../>
```

Or bind to it :

```
<local:ComboBox selectedValueList="{variableHoldingCommaDelimList}" ...rest of properties.../>
```

Let me know how it goes.  :)

Comment: Thanks Nate for your efforts.  Actually, there is already some code quite similar to your own in there.  I tried yours anyway (though I had to change it a bit (changed "set selectedValueList" to "setSelectedValueList" and change assignment method to passing a value as opposed to assigning)).

Unfortunately, still no joy.  The logic is correct as it works in other situations.  It's just that it doesn't work on startup.

Thanks again for your efforts though.  It's still appreciated.

Comment: Well, the one that was in there requires you to pass actual objects and this just a string.  By start up you mean when the application first loads or does this component get added to the screen dynamically like in a list / item renderer?  I think its a timing issue between creating the list and setting the values.

Comment: You can see the code in my edited post above.  It's similar to what you put.  I mean when the application first loads.  The text property is not being changed when the set method is being called.  Actually, during one debug session, I found that it worked as desired but this was a complete fluke which makes me think even more, as you do, that it's a timing issue.  I'm currently trying to come up with a (less desirable) solution as a workaround.  Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "set text" in case of a combobox. Rather it should be selectedIndex that you should be setting. Apart from that, instead of applicationComplete OR creationComplete, override commitProperties method and assign this initial property there (althought you can simply assign selectedIndex in mxml itself).

Comment: By "set text", I mean the setter method for the text property.  I wasn't sure how else to say it.

I can't use selectedIndex because there may be more than one item selected (due to the nature of the component and the data).

And I can't override the commitProperties method and just set the value there because, as I said, it needs to be set dynamically depending on the situation.  Thanks for the tip though.  It's a good one to remember.  I even tried calling commitProperties once the text property was set but no joy.

I believe the problem has something to do with the time it updates as it's..

Comment: ... only at startup.  Seems that the fact that the items are still being drawn means that they aren't being updated properly.  Possible Flex bug perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried using the selectedIndex or selectedItem property ?  The only reason I bring this up is because the Combobox is going to have a single selectedItem.  What you do in the renderer as far as selecting and unselecting is up to you, but the component itself is going to have one selectedItem.

Comment: @the_new_mr it would be great if you could post some code. As I mentioned above, if you handle the "addItems()" in the commitProperties, it would do the trick.

Comment: @FlexFiend selectedIndex is not enough because there may be more than one item selected at the same time

Comment: @M.D. I'll post some code in my original question. But as I said, the code does work... just not when the application is starting up.

Comment: @the_new_mr For once, try to use BindingUtils.bindSetter(setComboText, this, 'selectedItems'); Change 'this' to appropriate object. Just see if it works? Put it in creationComplete()